# find all $n$: for all $n$ real number, you could make all of them equal in finite number of steps, each step replace $a,b$ to $a+b, a+b$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

With a list of $n$ real numbers, in each step you can replace 2 arbitrary elements $a,b$ to $a+b, a+b$. Find all $n$ such that no matter what is the initial $n$ elements on the list, you can make all of them equal in finite numbers of steps.

In the original problem, the operation is $a,b$ to $\frac{a+b}2, \frac{a+b}2$ which is easier since the sum of all elements on that list is invariant. I tried to solve this problem for days with the goal of proving $n = 2^k$  but can't prove or disprove the case $n = 6$. I'm not sure if the solutions for $n$ remain the same if we change "real numbers" to "integers". But for the real case, I think choosing the $n$ initial elements linear independent over $\mathbb{Q}$ might help.

update: solution for the case of $2 \not|n$ and the case of $2|n$ and the initial list being a rational list is referenced in the comment bellow

update2: I found a solution for the general case: every even number work and every odd number don't

Comment: I have crossposted the question at [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/452221/136218).

Comment: Do you have a proof of impossibility for $n=5$?

Comment: I think the answer of the guy that solved for the case of $n=6$ and all the elements on the initial list are integer can be alternate to work with the case that $n$ is even and the initial list is a list of rational numbers

Comment: I am not convinced about this proof. We could "build" an n and then fix the remaining four numbers. Regarding the rational numbers, you can see in one comment that the setup is equivalent to one with integers only.

Comment: @jackdean: can you say a bit more about why there are always examples with an odd number of elements where it is impossible for the final $n$ not to appear on the original list, please.

Comment: An example of odd $n$ and a list that $N$ can not be appeared on can be $(3,2,2,...2)$, because of the operation and the list is full of positive number, every element on the list can only be increased so, if we could make all of them equal (aka to $(N,N,N...N)$) then it's easy to see that $N$ can neither be $2$ or $3$ and the numbers of elements equal to $N$ can only increased by $0$ or $2$ since there is no $0$ on the initial list.

Comment: I think, your proof of the impossibility of odd $n$ is correct.

Comment: Fixed solution for the case of odd $n$ because of mistyping:
With odd $n$, let the initial list be $(3,2,2,....2)$
1. Assume there is a $N$ that we can make all of them equal to $(N,N,...N)$
2. Since all elements on the list is positive so every time you replace $(a,b) -> (a+b,a+b)$, the number of elements equal to $N$ can only increased by $0$ or $2$
3. since then, there has to be odd numbers of elements equal to $N$ on the initial list, $N=2$ is impossible since there is a $3$ and $N=3$ is impossible because selecting $(2,any)$ make $(>4, >4)$ so the elements equal to $N$ is 0 (not odd)

Comment: We can standardize the initial list to the case where there's only 2 different number: $1, r$ because $r$ can be irrational so if we could make that list be $(N,N,N,....N)$. Such number $N$ has to be the form of  $a + b*r$ with $a,b$ is an integer depend only on the number of $1$ occur on the initial list. I think $N$ is the sum of all elements of the given list times a constant depend only on $n$ regardless whatever $r$ might be